# Nested Reactive Forms In Angular: markAsTouched being triggered when adding to form array?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, frontend, angular-reactive-forms

I'm currently working on an Angular application that involves creating a reactive form. The form is designed to capture user information along with details about associated clients. The main form consists of controls for the user's name and a dynamic array of client entries, which can be added or removed based on user input.

Below is a snippet of my component and its corresponding HTML template:

**TypeScript - mainForm.component.ts:**

```
export class mainFormComponent implements OnInit {
  mainForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      clients: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  get clientForm() {
    return this.adviserForm.get('clients') as FormArray;
  }

  addClient() {
    const client = this.fb.group({
      client_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
    this.clientForm.push(client);
  }

  deleteClient(i: number) {
    this.clientForm.removeAt(i);
  }

  submit() {
    this.mainForm.markAsAllTouched();
  }
}
```

**HTML - main-form.component.html:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" [formGroup]="mainForm">
  <input
    [ngClass]="{
      'invalid-input':
        adviserForm.get('name')?.invalid &&
        adviserForm.get('name')?.touched
    }"
    formControlName="adviser_name"
    placeholder="adviser name"
  />
  <hr />
  <h4>Clients</h4>
  <div formArrayName="clients">
    <div
      *ngFor="let client of clientForm.controls; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <input
        [ngClass]="{
          'invalid-input':
            client.get('client_name')?.invalid &&
            client.get('client_name')?.touched
        }"
        formControlName="client_name"
        placeholder="client name"
      />
      <button (click)="deleteClient(i)">Delete Client</button>
    </div>
    <button (click)="addClient()">Add Client</button>
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The main form features controls for the user's name and a dynamic array of client entries. Users can add or remove clients as needed. To provide validation feedback, I'm using the ngClass directive to apply the 'invalid-input' class to form controls that are both invalid and touched by the user.

The issue I have comes from the behaviour of ngClass, when I click 'Add Client' it is marking my input elements as touched.

My understanding is that it has something to do with Angular's default change detection triggering my marked state, how do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you add a required FormControl to form it becomes touched by default.

```
addClient() {
 const client = this.fb.group({
   client_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
 });
 this.clientForm.push(client);
 this.clientForm.markAsPristine();
}
```

This may help, if you mark it as pristine.

Answer (score 0):

To "reach" the FormControl use the dot notation with get

```
mainform.get('clients.'+i+'.client_name')

//or
clientForm.get(i+'.client_name')
```

BTW, Angular yet add the class ng-invalid and ng-touched to the input, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes), so

```
//instead defined your class invalid-input
.invalid-input{
  color:red;
  border:red;
}
//use
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
  color:red;
  border:red;
}
```

And you needn't take care about use the [ngClass]

NOTE: be careful, in your code you use `adviserForm` but the formGroup is `mainForm` (I imagine it was an error when you transcribed your question)